# 9-patch image error

Tags: android, android-studio, png, nine-patch, aapt

I have a project that builds and works, but my images (png) doesn't adapt to the phone.

Actually, I have 10 images, and I put them in all drawable folder : 
-drawable-hdpi have 10 images
-drawable-mdpi have the 10 SAMES images (same name, same size, same resolution)
- ... same for xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi

1) I tried to use Simple Nine-patch Generator, from AndroidAssetStudio this way : http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

- I took my first image, uploaded it onto the generator, downloaded the zip, and extracted each file in the proper folder.
- Then I run my app and I got this error :

  ERROR: 9-patch image ../../IMAGE_1.png malformed. Frame pixels must be
  either solid or transparent (not intermediate alphas)

2) Then I tried to go back to the original .png, and used /Android/Sdktools/draw9patch, and put the .9.png generated in the right folder.

And I got this error:

```
ERROR: 9-patch image ../../IMAGE_1.9.png malformed.
AAPT:        No marked region found along edge.
AAPT:        Found along top edge.
```

Here's one of my original images:

[image: p11_titre.png]

and here's the generated version :

[image]

Comment: I just share original image and the one modified with AndroidAssetStudio generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is your 9 patch.
There's a bad pixel on the bottom marker.

[image]

And this is how it will stretch, due to the markers you set.

[image]

---

This is my fixed version (note the top markers: 2 single pixels)

[image]

And this is how it nicely stretches (width only, because of the curved edges - You can add a transparent line on top and bottom to make it leave some "space", the left side markers would then have to be made 2 single pixels, one per each transparent line).

[image]

Comment: Where is the  bad pixel on the image? I can not see it. How can a pixel be "bad"?

Comment: Now I can't remember, after 6 months... ;) I guess I found a pixel which wasn't **full black**. And his makes it a **bad** pixel, for a 9 patch marker.